# Cannot find JavaScript script file from HTML file script

Tags: javascript, html, django

In the following [Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdzsb.png), I am trying to reference the javascript file "doggies.js" that is currently in the basket folder. This happens on the click of a button on my website, but every time it says it cannot find the file. I have tried ../doggies.js as well but this does not work, is there any reason as to why this might be happening?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('click', '.checkout-button', function () {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = "doggies.js"; 
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
      return false;
    console.log("yo")
  })
</script>
```

Here is the error

```
Not Found: /basket/doggies.js
[13/May/2021 18:50:22] "GET /basket/doggies.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3322
```

Comment: Are you using Django framework?

Comment: @Sophie yes I am using Django, does that affect things?

Comment: how do you import the file? share please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create static folder in your root directory add this line to settings.py

```html
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And load STATIC in your html file and use static to load the javascript files.

```html
{% load static %}


{% static 'js/doggies.js' %}
```

Comment: Can you check my answer then? 

Comment: Thanks. Let`s keep in touch.